# Rspec, testing AJAX, count list items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

My app has a dashboard with 3 columns.
All three columns represent a different state(field of model) of that object.

When in the first column it's 'pending', when you approve it, it goes to the 'accepted' column.

I start off by creating 3 objects, 1 in each column.

Then I want to be able to press the approve button of the first column and test if it moved to column 2.

This is the structure of the code currently:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 pending-candidates">
  <div class="collection-menu">
  <h1>Candidates</h1>
  <div class="icon-menu"></div>
  <i class="material-icons">done</i>
</div>

<ul id="applied-desktop-dashboard-ajax">  
  <li class="collection-item applied-candidate" id="pending_8"> <=== NEED TO COUNT THIS
    <div class="first-content">
      <div class="candidate-details">
        <a href="/employees/8">
          <h1>Patrick M.</h1>
        </a>      
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second-content" style="display: none;">
      <a data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="patch" href="/matchings/216?state=denied">
        <i class="material-icons close-deny">close</i>
      </a>    
      <a data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="patch" href="/matchings/216?state=accepted">
        <i class="material-icons close-accept">done</i>
      </a>  
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I try to accessing it like following:

```
expect(page).to have_selector('applied-desktop-dashboard-ajax li', count: 1)
expect(page).to have_css('applied-desktop-dashboard-ajax li', count: 1)
```

and it returns following error message:

```
expected to find css "applied-desktop-dashboard-ajax li" 1 time 
but there were no matches
```

same goes for when I only want to check if it has the ul (its always there even if it has no objects loaded in).

Anyone has an idea how to count the list items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just forgot the ID prefix (`#`) in your selector, it should be:

```
expect(page).to have_css('#applied-desktop-dashboard-ajax li', count: 1)
```